# Image security and linux file/directory permissions

Tags: php, linux, image, security

In a PHP app I am allowing users to upload photos.  Upon user upload, metadata is stored in the db and images are then stored in a directory on the linux server.  I only want these images to be viewable when called through a view so I can verify that the correct party is viewing them.  I do not want anyone to be able to just enter a url and view the image.

```
/site
   /framework
   /protected  /**My PHP site**/
   /www
      /images  /**This is where I am currently storing the images**/
```

1. In order to restrict viewing of these images do I need to move the `images` directory outside of `www`? If so to where?
2. What linux permissions should be given on the `images` directory?
3. For images that I have stored in my db that I want restricted access to I use access rules within my framework.  Can rules such as these limit access to images in a given directory also?

Any info that can be provided as to how to approach this (so I can do further research) as well as answers to the questions above will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all images in that directory to be denied (they ALL must be access through a script and none of them will have direct access available - ie only your server will be able to access them, and you have apache with `mod_rewrite`) you can put a `.htaccess` in that directory like the following:

```
deny from all
```

So to answer the questions by number.. ^^

1. No, the `.htaccess` will take care of it with the same effect.
2. You'll need read (`+r`) for the images for the server.
3. The framework may have something like that, but it can't prevent direct linking if the image URL is known.  Doing it with `.htaccess` or moving the directory would be the best bet.

Comment: Giving pts to the one with less.  Info from both you and Quentin helped me get to my solution.  In short I was able to move my images folder and protect it, rending images through my a php script.  So far it looks and appears to work as needed.

Answer (score 1):

> In order to restrict viewing of these images do I need to move the images directory outside of www?

No, but that is the most secure option.

> If so to where?

Anywhere

> What linux permissions should be given on the images directory?

The minimum you need for the server to read from and write to it. Possibly 700.

> For images that I have stored in my db that I want restricted access to I use access rules within my framework. Can rules such as these limit access to images in a given directory also?

Since the images are only available via PHP, the PHP can add whatever auth/authz you like.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use a `.htaccess` file and restrict people from entering that directory, as well as turn off directory listing just in case.